# Linux blocks my ports, how to unblock it?

Tags: linux, firewall

I use Centos 7. I disabled iptables:

```
sudo service iptables stop
sudo chkconfig iptables off
```

I also disbaled SeLinux:

```
$sestatus 
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

But ports are bolcked. Port 22 works, but if I change ssh server port (e.g. 2222) then ssh returns message:

```
No route to host
```

What blocks my ports and how o solve it?

**EDIT**

I changed sshd port because I wanted to check if that works. I wanted to be sure that ports are blocked. So when I set port to 2222 in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on machine1 and restart ssh service then following command from machine2 gives following result:

```
$ssh -X user@192.168.0.10 -p 2222
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.10 port 2222: No route to host
```

This example shows that ports are blocked. Really I can not connect to X server and I think that port blocking causes that.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you're trying to do. On a linux machine (call it machine1), you changed the port of the ssh server (sshd) to 2222 and from machine2 you can't connect to machine1?

Comment: @Jan You are right. I edited my question. But ssh is only example. really I can not connect to X server and I think that I can not connect to it because port 6000 is blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to stop **firewalld**, cause now in RH7 based OS firewalld replaces iptables.

Try to check if it is running:

```
systemctl status firewalld
```

If it is running, just stop it with:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

[More info](http://www.tejasbarot.com/2014/08/05/rhel-7-centos-7-how-to-get-started-with-firewalld/#axzz3E8YCsnRB)

Comment: I don't think it's best practice to just turn off the firewall.. I'd advise @Mariusz to look up the documentation of firewalld instead of just turning it off!

Comment: Yup. Firewalld's syntax is pretty simple and its worth doing it the *right* way

Answer (score 1):

"No route to host" - means something different than firewall is blocking the connection. It means your computer cannot figure out what network communication interface to use to get there - check that you are using the correct ip address or dns name for the remote machine